# weird Xcode issue making program behave incorrectly

Tags: c++, xcode

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class Rectangle
{
private:
    double width;
    double height;

public:
    Rectangle(double w, double h)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    void setWidth(double w)
    {
        width = w;
    }

    double getArea()
    {
        cout << "width = " << width << endl;
        cout << "height = " << height << endl;
        return width * height;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Rectangle rect1(3.5, 7.0);
    rect1.setWidth(10.0);
    double rect1Area = rect1.getArea();
    cout << rect1Area << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code produces the following (incorrect) output:

```
width = 3.5
height = 10
35
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

This is strange because the width is being set to 10, not the height.  Furthermore, if I just change the name of the setWidth method by deleting a letter or adding a letter (in both the definition and the function call of course), then the program gives the following (correct) output:

```
width = 10
height = 7
70
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I have tried cleaning and re-building, copying the code to a new file, quitting and re-starting Xcode and even re-booting my computer, but this behavior continues.  It's perplexing.  I'm using Xcode 7.3.1.  Any insights?

Comment: Do you have the command-line tools installed? If not, try installing them and tell us if you still have this problem when you run `clang++ <filename>` followed by `./a.out`.

Comment: (And if you do, try compiling & running anyway.)

Comment: It works correctly in Terminal, but not in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks. I use the terminal nearly exclusively (the only exception being an occasional run of Instruments) so I'm afraid I don't have any comments that could be more helpful. I asked because it ran just fine for me from the terminal. So that's a weird bug indeed.